# Php Error message from php to js

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Want to text the error but something is wrong with the code cause it only returns [object Object] , the errno number 0 is the succes .

```
if (ldap_errno($ldap) != 0) {
  $res = ldap_error($ldap);
  echo json_encode($res);
}
```

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  url: "php/main.php",
  success: function(res) { 
    $('#loadingmessage').hide();
    //cool things 
  },
  error: function(res) {
    $('#loadingmessage').hide();
    $(".mssg").text(res);
  }
});
```

Comment: `res` is an object, so cannot be directly appended to the DOM. If you `console.log(res)` you'll see the properties of the object. To fix the issue you need to set the `text()` to the required property of `res`, eg `$('.mssg').text(res.foo);`

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaanks! :)